# Auto-populating a Textarea with PHP variables

Tags: php, html, textarea

How do I auto-populate the text area below with two PHP variables, $submission and $fullurl?

```
<form method='post' action='index.php'>

<br />

<textarea  name="tweet" cols="50" rows="5" id="tweet" ></textarea>

<br />

<input type='submit' value='Tweet' name='submit' id='submit' />

</form>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<textarea>`s are given default values like so:

```
<textarea>value</textarea>
```

So use something like:

```
<textarea name="tweet" cols="50"rows="5" id="tweet"><?php echo $submission ?> <?php echo $fullurl ?></textarea>
```

Note that any whitespace is represented as-is in a textarea, so newlines will result in newlines in the textbox.