# Image path is not displaying into textbox

Tags: php

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction() {
 //var query = '?';
     var str = $("form").serialize();
    str = str.replace(/\=/g, "='").replace(/\&/g, "'&");
    $( "#results" ).text(str+"'" );  
     var x = $("#results").text();
return x;

}
 
$('#myButton').on('click',function(){    
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myFunction());
    console.log(jsonString);

 $.ajax({
    url: 'insert_value.php',
    data: jsonString,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
  }).done(function(resp) {
    $('#result').html(resp)

  });
  });  

  </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>


<?php 
include("con_gen.php");

error_reporting(E_ALL);

// DATABASE CONNECTION AND SELECTION VARIABLES - GET THESE FROM YOUR HOSTING COMPANY
$db_host = "localhost"; // PROBABLY THIS IS OK
$db_name = "idcard";
$db_user = "root";
$db_word = "";

// OPEN A CONNECTION TO THE DATA BASE SERVER AND SELECT THE DB
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_word, $db_name);

// DID THE CONNECT/SELECT WORK OR FAIL?
if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    $err
    = "CONNECT FAIL: "
    . $mysqli->connect_errno
    . ' '
    . $mysqli->connect_error
    ;
    trigger_error($err, E_USER_ERROR);
}

// RUN A QUERY
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT value FROM combo1");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

//echo "$num_rows Rows\n";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
  $array = Array();
  $array1 = Array();
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         //echo "<br> value: ". $row['value'].  "<br>";
          $array[] = $row['value'];
        
}
//print_r($array);

$sql = "SELECT static_name FROM static_values";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                //echo "<option>" . $row['static_name'] . "</option>";
                $array1[]=$row['static_name'];
                 
                 //echo $source;
               }
              // print_r($array1);
               foreach ($array as $row)
{
  if(in_array($row, $array1))
  {
$sql = "SELECT source_table,Alias_name FROM static_values where static_name='$row'";
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);

// DID THE QUERY WORK OR FAIL?
if (!$res)
{
    $err
    = 'QUERY FAILURE:'
    . ' ERRNO: '
    . $mysqli->errno
    . ' ERROR: '
    . $mysqli->error
    . ' QUERY: '
    . $sql
    ;
    trigger_error($err, E_USER_ERROR);
}

// ARE THERE ANY ROWS IN THE RESULTS SET

if ($res->num_rows == 0)
{
    trigger_error("ERROR: NO DATA FOUND BY $sql", E_USER_ERROR);
}

// RETRIEVE THE ROWS INTO AN ARRAY OF HTML STATEMENTS
//$html = "";
echo '<form method="POST" action="" id="myform">';

while ($row = $res->fetch_object())
{
    //$html =$html.' 
  echo'
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="row-fluid">

      <div class="span3 bgcolor">
     <label>'.$row->Alias_name.'</label>


        <select  id='.$row->source_table.' name='.$row->source_table.' data-live-search="true" class="selectpicker form-control" type="sel">';

  /*foreach ( $Data->{$row->source_table} as $key =>$item) {
    echo "<option value=".$key.">".$item."</option>" ;
  }*/
   foreach ( $Data->{$row->source_table} as $key =>$item)  {
    echo "<option value=".$key.">".$item."</option>";
  }
echo '         
          </select> 
                                          </div>
      </div>
  </td>
</tr>';
}
}
else if($row=="Image")
{
  echo '
<tr>
  <td>
   <div class="row-fluid">
               
            <div class="span3 bgcolor">
            <label>'.$row.'</label>
               <label>'.$row.'</label>
               <input type="file" name="'.$row.'" id="'.$row.'" onchange="document.getElementById(\''.$row.'\').value = this.value">
                <input type="text" name="'.$row.'" id="'.$row.'" value="'.$imagepath.'">
            
</div>
</div>
  </td>
</tr>';
   }
   else
   {
   //$html =$html.' 
  echo '
<tr>
  <td>
   <div class="row-fluid">
               
            <div class="span3 bgcolor">
            <label>'.$row.'</label>
                 <input id='.$row.' type="text" placeholder=" Enter Value " name='.$row.' style="width:100%" class="form-control" required="" />
                              
                </select> 
</div>
</div>
  </td>
</tr>';

}

}
echo'<input  id="myButton" type="button" value="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-success"  name="submit" onclick="myFunction();"/>';
echo '<p id="results">&nbsp;</p>';
echo '<pre id="result"></pre></form> ';

//echo '<p><tt id="results"></tt></p>';
}



               ?>
               </body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php else if($row=="Image")
{
    echo '<tr>
             <td>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span3 bgcolor">
                        <label>'.$row.'</label>
       <input type="file" name='.$row.' id='.$row.' onchange="document.getElementById('.$row.').value = this.value">
    <input type="text" name='.$row.' id='.$row.'>
       </div>
  </div>
      </td>
 </tr>';
?>
```

Here I'm reading image full path within textbox and inserting into database but here image path is not coming into textbox  please tell me solution

I posted my whole  code  please let me know the solution how to get image path into text box

Comment: you should use the `value` attribute in the textbox

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812274/auto-populating-a-textarea-with-php-variables

Comment: are you able to post the rest of the code prior to and after this snippet? It would make it easier to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It's hard to provide a proper answer with so little context, but my guess is that your row variable contain much more than the string "Image", that's why your if-statement fails

Comment: No offense, but, if this code goes into a db, isn't it prone to sql injection if you dont validate the image url?

Comment: try my answer @shruti

Comment: @tyrone i'll post

Comment: If you php code is rendering correct. you must check the browser html elements that how it has been rendered.

Comment: yaa its rendering correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need value attribute and every attribute value should be enclosed by single quotes or double quotes like this

```
<?php
echo '<tr>
        <td>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span3 bgcolor">
                    <label>'.$row.'</label>
                    <input type="file" name="'.$row.'" id="'.$row.'" onchange="document.getElementById(\''.$row.'\').value = this.value">
                    <input type="text" name="'.$row.'" id="'.$row.'" value="'.$imagepath.'">
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>';
?>
```

Comment: ya tried it gives like thisNotice: Undefined variable: imagepath in C:\xampp\htdocs\dyn_html.php on line 136

Comment: @shruti you need to enter the value for `$imagepath` yourself

Comment: sorry I'm getting what you are going to tell

Answer (score 0):

Check this example code and verify whether the id you are getting is correct.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="data">
 <input type="file" name='fileTest' id='FileTest' onchange="document.getElementById('test').value = this.value">
  <input type="text" name='test' id='test'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try checking the id name after page render whether it is embedded in double qoutes

Comment: can you update the code after page renders from the browser

Answer (score 0):

Ok so looking at the code and one of your comments it seems `$imagepath` is not declared anywhere prior to being called. You need to declare `$imagepath`, then set it's value before you can call it. Failure to declare the variable prior to calling it will result in an error, failure to set the variable will result in nothing being returned when it's called.